# Analog Reference and Power Voltage

Tags: analogread

On the Arduino website it states that the analog pins read voltages from 0 to 5 volts (default) and return a value from 0 to 1023. One can also set the range with analogReference(). However, this is probably assuming the Arduino is running at 5 volts. If one powers the board with, say 4 volts, will the analog reference still be 5 volts default, or changed to the input voltage of 4 volts?

Comment: A reading of 1023 will mean 4V if the board is powered using 4V. 1023 means supply voltage, which is not necessarily 5V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct. Calling `analogReference()` with a value of `DEFAULT` sets the ADC reference to the voltage at AV<sub>CC</sub> which at least on the Uno R3 is tied directly to V<sub>CC</sub> and hence has the same voltage as whatever you're supplying there.

Answer (score 0):

There is code published that shows how to read the internal voltage, I use that to correct my A/D readings. It is not perfect but close. You can of course select a lower reference voltage by changing the appropriate registers and use a different reference. This is much safer then supplying an external reference.